# Mongo positional projection $

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

As per the official mongo documentation i can retrieve first element of an array using this,

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1, grades: { $gte: 85 } }, { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

But i want all first array elements with out grades:  *{ $gte: 85 }*  filter,

```
    db.students.find( { semester: 1}, { "grades.$": 1 } )
```

But i m getting below error for that,

Positional projection 'grades.$' does not match the query document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$slice operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/), which returns the first X elements of an array, which you can set to 1:

```
db.students.find( { semester: 1}, { "grades": { $slice: 1 } } )
```